# The Missing Taste

Tags: word, wordplay, knowledge, story

> After a tiring *soccer* match which I *absquatulated* because I got
>   *insulted* all the time by my own teammates, I went to my regular
>   restaurant and ordered a fancy *sashimi* “the *agushi* special” but the
>   waitress said it’s ran out so I had no other choice but to order a
>   regular set.
>
> The waitress suggested a sake pairing but it’s really not my *cup* of
>   tea, especially the ‘*Amabuki*’ brand they serve there, so I ordered my
>   usual go-to drink, *Macallan* on the rock, but the drink they brought me
>   taste so much *sweet*er than I remembered. I’m not even sure that’s
>   actually Macallan.
>
> The food service was so slow, I had to walk to the restaurant bar and
>   ate all the *nut* snacks they have on the counter which was also taste very
>   bad because they weirdly mix it with dried *pumpkins*. Suffice to say, I
>   did not enjoy the meal at all.
>
> Just when I thought my bad luck was over, when I got back to my
>   apartment, my *stoner* roommate was getting high all day and forgot to
>   water my *plant*! I decided to go to bed early and end this day asap but
>   then after I revisioned my whole bad day in my head; I suddenly craved a
>   taste of something. I thought to myself maybe that taste will finally
>   fulfill what is missing from this bad day, and it did!

What did I eat?

---

Edit & hint I:

> See *italic*.

Hint II:

> I've omitted the tag [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern) since It was only somewhat relevant but perhaps it will be more useful as a hint.

Comment: Maybe add another hint? Bookmarked this puzzle since it came out and it hasn't had any activity in almost a month :(

Comment: @S.M. Thank you for putting up the bounty and for the hint; maybe my new comment to Astralbee's answer will be of use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrone has pretty much given everything away, but there'd better be an answer tying it together. I am still pretty unsure of some of the details here.

The taste you were feeling the lack of was

> butter.

In each of your frustrating incidents

> there is some combination of X and butter-X (e.g., scotch and butterscotch), and having had, or had cause to think about, all those butter-X things made you feel that you needed butter too. (So, at least, I understand OP's comments after I expressed some confusion as to why these coincidences should make you want butter.)

You played *soccer* but *absquatulated* because you were *insulted*.

> I remain rather confused by these. I wondered whether you were insulted by being called a *butterball* (soccer is called *football* rather than merely *ball*, but I guess one speaks of children "playing ball" for any number of different games, of which soccer would be one), but OP's comments suggest that that wasn't the idea. As for *absquatulated*, I guess it's not too far from meaning the same as "fly" -- but I don't see any butterflies in the text. There really ought to be a word beginning "butter" that's close in meaning to "absquatulate" and "insult", but I can't find one.

Your *cup* of tea isn't the *Amabuki* sake.

> Amabuki sell sake made with various different "flower yeasts". I can't actually find *buttercup* on their list, but I assume it's one of them.

You ordered *sashimi* but didn't get the *agushi* special you wanted.

> It seems like something rather indirect is going on here. Agushi means gourd seeds. There is a kind of fish that is sometimes called the "melon seed"; it is also called the *Japanese butterfish*. So you got ordinary *Japanese fish* instead. (This is the opposite way around from some of the other cases below: here you wanted butter-X but got X, but in the other cases you wanted X but got butter-X.)

You ordered a *Macallan* but got something too *sweet*.

> You got *butterscotch* instead of *scotch*.

You ate some *nuts* but they were mixed with dried *pumpkin*.

> You wanted *nuts* and got *butternut* squash (which isn't actually the same thing as pumpkin, but they're similar enough that you-in-the-story might have confused one for the other -- and OP informs me in comments that in some parts of the world they call it "butternut pumpkin", which I'd had no idea of).

Your *stoner* friend forgot to water your *plant*.

> He was too busy with his *weed* to tend to your *butterweed*.

I'm really just filling in details already sketched by Chrone in comments, so if you like this answer I suggest you go and upvote Astralbee's instead.

Comment: rot13(Ohggreonyy vf hfrq gb ersre gb n qvssrerag guvat urer. Nofdhnghyngr zrnaf "gb dhvg fbzrguvat noehcgyl", jung'f nabgure jbeq gung tvirf n fvzvyne frafr?  Fnzr tbrf jvgu *vafhyg*. Fnfuvzv vf n svfu qvfu sebz **Wncnarfr**, fb vg znxrf zber frafr gung gur svfu vf abg Nzrevpna. Jung'f nabgure anzr sbe gurz? Ohggreahg Fdhnfu vf npghnyyl fbzrgvzrf pnyyrq Ohggreahg Chzcxva va Nhfgenyvn/ Arj Mrnynaq.)

Comment: Now for the matter of why I want the taste of *the answer*, it's simply because all of the things I encountered today are its suffix and that's why **"when I revisioned my whole bad day in my head; I suddenly craved a taste of it"**. From the puzzle standpoint: the answer is missing from all these suffix in spite of the presence of their meaning.

Comment: Still pretty confused by the soccer insults and absquatulation. Have adjusted my answer elsewhere in the light of those comments. Sorry to be being slow on the uptake.

Comment: The ____ball is referring to a brand of _____? The similar word of "insulted" is both “smoked” and “roasted”; smoke is a clue for absquatulated and roast is for ____ball. About the Agushi *or Egusi*, here's a wiki article about it: [Egusi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egusi). You may be overthinking this a little bit. Gur vqrn vf rirelguvat gung V qvq abg trg sbe nal ernfba be trg ohg gnfgrf onq be birenyy ehvarq zl qnl vf n fhssvk gung zvffvat vgf cersvk “ohggre”, be va gur zrgncubevpny frafr, vg’f zvffvat “gur gnfgr bs "ohggre”.

Comment: According to Chrone's comments I feel like this answer comes closest to the intended one (flabalzf bs gur jbeqf va vgnyvp pna or cersvkrq jvgu "ohggre"), so I'll award it the bounty even though there's hasn't been an accepted answer yet.

Answer (score 13):

Is the answer simply:

> Butternut Squash

Because...

> Throughout the story you mention the foods you *wanted* to eat, and the foods you were served but did not enjoy. You wanted to eat:
>
>  - "Agushi" - which is the seeds from cucurbitaceous plants like the **squash**,
>  - "Macallan" - which is a single malt *whiskey*, and whiskey is associated with **butter**, ie whiskey-butter, butter*scotch*.
>  - "**Nuts**" (but you got pumpkin seeds instead).
>
>  Put them all together and you get Butter-Nut-Squash.

Comment: Wow, that’s very interesting! I didn't know about that menu before. You're so *close* and certainly on the right track but I ate just this one simple thing (that people don’t normally eat the way I do) and it's not even a meal. If you finally get the answer and I know you will, find all the *other* clues scattered around the story and explain how it connects to my answer then I’ll green-check it.

Comment: I can't believe you didn't even provide the [obligatory link](https://www.geniuskitchen.com/recipe/bourbon-butternut-squash-soup-152711)!

Comment: @Chowzen There is a recipe but it's on a paywall site so I thought it was pointless.

Comment: You missed the "s" of sweet in saisacamsnpsp

Comment: That's strange.. I didn't down vote this, but it's showing that I did and now I can't remove the down vote.. what gives?

Comment: This is wicked frustrating because I want to up-vote this and it's not letting me, claiming I gave it a down vote, which I did NOT.

Comment: @Astralbee Your first guess is actually way more closer than this one. It’s like you already got all the important bit and pieces to form the correct answer but you connected it or looked at it the wrong way.

Comment: @mkinson you must have downvoted by accident. Now that I have edited my answer again, you will be able to change your vote if you wish.

Comment: @Chrone Ok I've had another go. Closer to previous answer, sort of.

Comment: @Astralbee But how would you explain all the other italics? Ok, I think your answer is close enough that I’ll allow a giveaway. Rot13(Gur gnfgr bs *ahg* naq *fdhnfu* vfa'g ernyyl zvffvat sebz zl qnl be gur fgbel, vf vg?  V zrna V fnvq fb zlfrys V ngr yvxr n jubyr onfxrg bs gurz. Abj pebff gurz bhg, jung’f yrsg?) You got the answer right in your hand, all you need to do is look deeper into the story and find some kind of pattern to affirm it then everything will be clicked. Which, by the way, you seem to already notice *some* of the connections but unaware of its importance.

Comment: For what it's worth, when you commented on my answer I wondered about exactly what you're pointing to now, but I wasn't able to link it to most of the words. I still can't, so far...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Maybe this will help you: | **soccer**, *absquatulated/insulted* | **cup**, *Amabuki* | **sashimi**, *agushi* | **Macallan**, *sweet* | **nut**, *pumpkin* | **stoner** (this one might be a bit misleading), *plant* |

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you ate a

> squash.

Let's take a look at those italicized words.

After a tiring *soccer* match

> You would have preferred to play *squash*.

which I *absquatulated*

> A most unusual way to say "left". Perhaps that *squa* in the middle reminded you of something you wanted.

because I got *insulted* all the time by my own teammates,

> Not sure about this (but your own teammates would be the *squad*, perhaps).

ordered a fancy *sashimi*

> Not sure about this, but maybe you asked for *squid*? Or maybe *sash*... was close enough to *squash* to get your hopes up?

“the *agushi* special”

> You wanted *squash* seeds. (And, probably coincidentally, AGUSHI and SQUASH have quite a lot of their letters in common.)

it’s really not my *cup* of tea, especially the ‘*Amabuki*’ brand they serve there, so I ordered my usual go-to drink, *Macallan* on the rock,

> Not sure what's going on with these. But perhaps you wanted a *gourd* rather than a *cup*, and perhaps *Scotch* sounded enough like *squash*.

the drink they brought me taste so much _sweet_er than I remembered.

> They brought you *squash*. But not *that* sort of squash!

and ate all the *nut* snacks they have on the counter

> Perhaps you were thinking about *butternut squash*?

they weirdly mix it with dried *pumpkins*

> A pumpkin is a kind of squash. (Not sure why that didn't scratch your itch.)

my *stoner* roommate was getting high all day

> Not sure what this is about. (Coincidence of letters between HASH and SQUASH, maybe? I doubt it.)

and forgot to water my *plant*!

> Probably a vine of the genus *Cucurbita*.

Credit where due: This is really a variation and elaboration on the first version of Astralbee's answer. If you like this one, you might consider upvoting that one too, even though that answer as it is *now* is miles off if this one is close to being right :-). Or find another answer of Astralbee's and upvote that.

Comment: Perhaps there might be another word from Astralbee’s answer that would fit every clues better? Maybe it's something you and Astralbee already wrote in your answers but didn’t pay much attention to it.